# Move top navigation bar along with the screen

Tags: android

I think the way I was going is wrong. I wanted to create a top navigation bar which has 3 items so I created tabs and with a View Pager, I used 3 fragments for each tab. That way I can slide screens between each other, but the tabs are not moving along with the screen.

Can someone suggest me how to make top navigation bar items moving along with the screen is sliding?

This video explains exactly what I want. Please note how the top bar items are moving along with the screen.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OzDFR4VT_YyDumEZLOWtGZ-_5BLXAfK4/view

Comment: use a TabLayout and make it scrollable  (app:tabMode="scrollable")

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I tried that, but its not behave as in the video, note the distance of moving when screen is sliding. screen slides whole width of the screen and tab is half